# Is it possible to change Kafka Topic config without data loss?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to change Kafka Topic config, can I preserve my data and offset data with config change?
I'm wondering if message and offset info is removed when I change partition num 1 to 3 (or I change compression type gzip to lz4)
Or recreate after remove?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing partitions doesn't modify any data in the original partition set, so it'd be unlikely to lose any.

I'm not sure if topic compression can be modified after the fact, but if it were, data would need re-written in the segment files over all the brokers, which opens the possibility for corruption. The safer approach would be to consume the original compressed topic and write it to a new compression type

"Recreate after remove" a topic? - of course you're losing the original data. If you mean any other config, outside of retention settings or cleanup policy, nothing comes to mind